# Every page refresh while logged-in brought me back to dashboard (persistent login with protected route)

Tags: reactjs, persistence, react-router-dom

I've implement a simple `protected route` from `Login` & other **protected** `components`.

- I'm using `universal-cookie` to **persist** user **data/token**
- On **protected route component**, I make sure to **always** check whether the **user exist** or **cookie exist**, thus **user is LOGIN**. Otherwise, no. This is done with `Context API`

#### Protected Route for `Login.js`

- this **protected route** is here to make sure if **user cookie exist** or **user authenticate**, then user should be `redirect` to `Dashboard.js` (home page for logged-in users)
- `ProtectedRouteLogin.js`:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthState'
import { isAuthenticated, setLoading } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthAction'

const ProtectedRoute\Login = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useAuth()
  const { authenticated, loading } = authState

  // check if user is authenticated
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await isAuthenticated(authDispatch)
      setLoading(authDispatch, false)
    })();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest} render={
        props => {
          if(loading) return <div className="lds-hourglass"></div>
          if(!authenticated) return <Component {...props} />
          else return <Redirect exact to={{
            // here I redirect logged-in user to dashboard
            pathname: "/dashboard",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }} />
        }
      } 
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRouteLogin
```

#### Protected Route for `Dashboard.js` or other protected components

- this exist for the same purpose as before, checking whether **user is authenticated or not**. If **YES**, then **render** the **protected** `component`. Otherwise, `redirect` to `Login` page
- `ProtectedRouteOthers.js`:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthState'
import { isAuthenticated, setLoading } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthAction'

const ProtectedRouteOthers = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useAuth()
  const { authenticated, loading } = authState

  // check if user is authenticated
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await isAuthenticated(authDispatch)
      setLoading(authDispatch, false)
    })();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Route 
      {...rest} render={
        props => {
          if(loading) return <div className="lds-hourglass"></div>
          if(authenticated) return <Component {...props} />
          else return <Redirect to={
            {
              // here redirect NOT logged-in user back to login page
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }
          } />
        }
      } 
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRouteOthers
```

#### Issues facing

- Since the checking (**user aunthentication**) is **done** in **protected route** layer or `component` just before `rendering` any **protected routes**, I'm having an issue where whenever I **refreshed** page (**when logged-in**). It keeps bring me back to `Dashboard.js` page.
- I reckoned, this have something todo with **having** my `authenticated` `state` in `Context API` is `false` by `default`. Every time, I hit **refreshed**, the `authenticated` `state` will be `false` first in `default` `state` until I **change/update** it, after checking **user cookie exist or not**. (this is done in `isAunthenticated` function in `Context API` which was called in both **Protected Routed** above)
- `isAuthenticated` function (check if user have cookie or not)

```js
export const isAuthenticated = async(dispatch) => {
  setLoading(dispatch, true)

  // get user cookie
  let userExist = getCookie('user')

  /** Cookie Checking Style */
  if(userExist) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_ISAUTHENTICATED',
      payload: true
    })
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: 'SET_ISAUTHENTICATED',
      payload: false
    })
  }
}
```

So how can I alter my code so that, every time i **refresh** my **protected** page (**when logged-in**). I **will stay on the refreshed page**, instead of **going back to the `Dashboard` page**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I found a **solution**. But I don't know whether this is an acceptable solution or not. At least this **logic make sense** to overcome my issue.

I decided to **add a logic** before rendering `Login.js` page & other **protected** `components` in both `Protected Route components` (logic added in `ProtectedRouteLogin.js` & `ProtectedRouteOthers`)

#### Logic added in `ProtectedRouteLogin.js`

- here before rendering to `Dashboard.js` page, if **user is authenticated**, I check for `props.location.pathname` **saved** in `cookie` **first**. If **present/exist**, then `render` to said `pathname`. Otherwise, just `render` to `Dashboard.js` page
- `ProtectedRouteLogin.js`:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthState'
import { isAuthenticated, setLoading } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthAction'
import { getCookie } from '../../../services/Cookie'

const ProtectedRouteLogin = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useAuth()
  const { authenticated, loading } = authState

  // check if user is authenticated
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await isAuthenticated(authDispatch)
      setLoading(authDispatch, false)
    })();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest} render={
        props => {
          if(loading) return <div className="lds-hourglass"></div>
          if(!authenticated) return <Component {...props} />
          else {
            // get pathname save in cookie
            let url = getCookie('onRefresh')
            
            return <Redirect exact to={{
              // ternary function to determine redirection
              pathname: url !== '' ? url : '/pfv4-admin/dashboard',
              state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
          }
        }
      } 
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRouteLogin
```

#### Logic added in `ProtectedRouteOthers.js`

- here, before rendering to **any protected** `components`, I **set** `cookie` that gonna **hold** the `props.location.pathname` or **url** of about-to visit `component`. So that, I can **cross-check** this **url** in `ProtectedRouteLogin.js` above.
- `ProtectedRouteOthers.js`:-

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useAuth } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthState'
import { isAuthenticated, setLoading } from '../../../contexts/Auth/AuthAction'
import { setCookie } from '../../../services/Cookie'

const ProtectedRouteOthers = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [authState, authDispatch] = useAuth()
  const { authenticated, loading } = authState

  // check if user is authenticated
  useEffect(() => {
    (async() => {
      await isAuthenticated(authDispatch)
      setLoading(authDispatch, false)
    })();
  }, [])

  return (
    <Route 
      {...rest} render={
        props => {
          if(loading) return <div className="lds-hourglass"></div>
          if(authenticated) {
            // save last page seen address (url)
            setCookie('onRefresh', props.location.pathname, { path: '/' }) 
            return <Component {...props} />
          }
          else return <Redirect to={
            {
              pathname: "/pfv4-admin",
              state: { from: props.location }
            }
          } />
        }
      } 
    />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRouteOthers
```

Feel free to add your own possible solution for this issue tho. Looking forward to try them.